# Setup laravel app on digitalocen

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, digital-ocean

I an trying to get my Laravel site running on Digital Ocean. My laravel app is static so no SQL is used and I developed it locally with Homestead.

I can get the site showing the home page on IPaddress /public. It won't link to any pages though. I am guessing it is some rewrite problem I am having. I want to get rid of the /public and get it linking to other pages. Then worry about making it work on a domain

I followed PHPAcademys Cloud Server Set-up tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1-ok9d_6xrc
The only difference is I used UBUNTU 14.04 x64. While following the tutorial I found I had a html folder inside /var/www. I needed to put my app within the html folder.

Code setup

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache 2
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt
```

I didnt use mysql because i dont need it for this app. Its a static site with laravel.

It said mcrypt was needed so I used

```
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Then I was getting an exception handler error, so i fixed that with

```
chgrp -R www-data /var/www/html
chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/app/storage
```

Comment: Your steps looks correct.  Did you setup an apache virtual host under /etc/apache2/sites-available ?

Comment: No, not on this one. I did while following a different tutorial, but I wasnt even getting the home page - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-laravel-with-nginx-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-lts-vps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup an apache2 virtual host

cd /etc/apache2/sites-available

sudo nano myapp.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myapp.com
    ServerAlias www.myapp.com

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/myapp/public"
    <Directory "/var/www/html/myapp/public/">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

exit nano

```
sudo a2ensite myapp.conf
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

First go to your virtual host file which can be found on

```
 /etc/apache2/sites-available/default.conf
```

I am not very sure about the path because I have been using nginx for so long. Anyways locate the conf file and change your root directory to something like

```
/var/www/html/public
```

rest all looks fine to me if that doesn't work chmod 777 app/storage